# Work from home in hotel room

Tags: wireless-networking

So I’m thinking about getting a room at an extended stay hotel but they only offer WiFi and the company I work for from home requires a direct connection how can I accomplish this if I move?

Comment: What is a "direct connection"?

Comment: Ethernet cable?

Comment: Yes I can’t use the platform over Wi-Fi

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you mean a VPN (Virtual Private Network) connection. If the company has any competence and an ongoing requirement for home workers then they should be implementing their own and should be able to instruct you on what to do.

Comment: The platform does require you to use the companies own VPN but it also requires an ethernet connection it can’t be used over Wi-Fi

Answer (score 0):

Hotel rooms and like connections may introduce a double NAT so the VPN client you use for travelling must accommodate (work through) double NAT.  I also suggest that you ask your company IT department.

Comment: I just started working for this company I sent them an email inquiring about while you were traveling but they haven’t sent it back yet in a place that I’m staying the guy selling the house and I have to be out in just a few days I’m afraid I won’t get a response back before I’m forced to move and then unable to work

Comment: @Ashley, it may be worth a phone call to the IT department to discuss your situation.